# Use existing SQLite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to use an existing `SQLite` database into my android application. I searched the web and came up with [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database?lq=1).

However from what I have understood from this approach, it creates a copy of my database. But suppose I have a 30 mb database, this method will take an additional 30 mb of space on the device.

Is there any way to get past this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achive?

Comment: It's not going to create a copy, i.e. duplicate, of your database. You're just going to treat the database as an asset that is loaded with the application, almost like a resource file. The database being 30 mb is going to be a problem for download/initial install. Is there anyway you could update/load some of the data after install from a webservice?

Comment: A way which circumvents this problem. An extra copy of database is created which is consuming some extra memory. I don't want that.

Comment: @Rarw: Well actually my database is not that big. While going through the solution, I assumed that a duplicate of database is created. This view was bolstered by some comments in that answer. However if you say that a copy of the database is not created, then actually what happens ?

Comment: Well it would take up more space than if you created the database on the device at runtime but not necessarily the whole size of the database. I like [this approach](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) which allows you to zip the database file and load it at runtime. But you're right in that extra space will be used since you cannot add/remove files from assets at runtime. I have, however, seen examples where the database was created on external storage but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @Rarw: Thanks for your help. But by default I'd like to keep my database on the internal memory.